# cmake and eclipse: default include paths?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that builds with CMake system, and I like to import it in Eclipse.
However, when I generate eclipse project files with 'cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"'
there are no default include paths in Eclipse project(such as /usr/include' or the gcc path for standard headers).

How to fix that in most right way?

System:
linux
gcc 4.3.3
cmake 2.6.4
eclipse 3.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to go to the project properties (right button over the project), "C/C++ include paths and symbols" and add them here as "external include paths".

Comment: The change should be done in CMakeList.txt, since Eclipse project files are generqated

Comment: I know, but only once. When CMakeList files change
 do not modify this settings into the Eclipse project. Adding standard headers to the eclipse project is only to allow the indexer to find them, but not related with the building process.

Comment: fnieto is right, or at least what he says is the only solution I knew. As far as i know there is no better solution.

Answer (score 6):

In your CMakeLists.txt try adding the following two lines:

```
find_path(STDIO_INCLUDE_PATH stdio.h)
include_directories("${STDIO_INCLUDE_PATH}/dummy/../")
```

The first line looks up the path for `stdio.h`, which is located in `/usr/include` on my system. The second adds this folder to the CMake include path. The `/dummy/../` part was added to trick CMake into adding the folder (it wouldn't otherwise), and will eventually get stripped off.

This works for me with CMake 2.8.8 and Eclipse 3.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the list of directories directly from the compiler, so you know you are getting the exact same set that CMake is using (assuming your CMake setup is using the same compiler). Then, split them into a list with [separate_arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148384/265487), and add them with the `include_directories` command.

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND echo
    COMMAND bash -c "g++ -E -Wp,-v - 2>&1"
    COMMAND awk "/^#include .* starts here:$/,/^End of search list/ { if ($0 ~ /^ /) { print } }"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE SYS_INCLUDES_OUT)
separate_arguments(SYS_INCLUDES UNIX_COMMAND ${SYS_INCLUDES_OUT}) # create a list
include_directories(${SYS_INCLUDES}) # add list to includes
```

They will then be included in the generated Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION=<put here your eclipse version>  ../src
```

for my case was

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2  ../src
```

I hope it helps