# What is common way to split string into list with CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

Imagine I have the following string :

```
set(SEXY_STRING "I love CMake")
```

then I want to obtain `SEXY_LIST` from `SEXY_STRING` so I can do

```
list(LENGTH SEXY_LIST len)
```

and `len` is equal 3.

I've found several macros on web, but I really want to know how to do it in "natural" way. This operation seems to be very basic and widely used.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Replace your separator by a `;`. I don't see any other way to do it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(SEXY_STRING "I love CMake")
string(REPLACE " " ";" SEXY_LIST ${SEXY_STRING})

message(STATUS "string = ${SEXY_STRING}")
# string = I love CMake

message(STATUS "list = ${SEXY_LIST}")
# list = I;love;CMake

list(LENGTH SEXY_LIST len)
message(STATUS "len = ${len}")
# len = 3
```

Comment: I've found a method that is a bit more general, but yours is also nice. Thanks!

Comment: You don't really required 2.8.
I am sure 2.6 works. maybe even 2.4

Comment: To avoid errors on empty lists, put the input in quotes: `string(REPLACE " " ";" SEXY_LIST "${SEXY_STRING}")`

Answer (score 49):

You can use the [`separate_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/separate_arguments.html) command.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(SEXY_STRING "I love CMake")

message(STATUS "string = ${SEXY_STRING}")
# string = I love CMake

set( SEXY_LIST ${SEXY_STRING} )
separate_arguments(SEXY_LIST)

message(STATUS "list = ${SEXY_LIST}")
# list = I;love;CMake

list(LENGTH SEXY_LIST len)
message(STATUS "len = ${len}")
# len = 3
```

Comment: Using `separate_arguments()` in a `macro()` on Linux had to be `separate_arguments(args UNIX_COMMAND "${ARGS}")` if ARGS is the argument name for the macro.

Answer (score 23):

```
string(REGEX MATCHALL "[a-zA-Z]+\ |[a-zA-Z]+$" SEXY_LIST "${SEXY_STRING}")
```

Comment: This may be a better solution. (Quote from http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html) #REGEX MATCHALL will match the regular expression as many times as possible and store the matches in the output variable as a ***list***.

Comment: I'm using ***string(REGEX MATCHALL "([^\ ]+\ |[^\ ]+$)" ARG_LIST "${ARGN}")***