# CMake Error on second run parsing execute_process output

Tags: string, list, cmake, makefile

I am trying to follow instructions from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658684/136285

So I wrote the following naive implementation:

```
% cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(p)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/demo.cmake
  ERROR_VARIABLE my_VERSION)
message("1: ${my_VERSION}")
string(REPLACE "." ";" my_VERSION_LIST "${my_VERSION}")
list(GET my_VERSION_LIST 0 my_VERSION_MAJOR)
list(GET my_VERSION_LIST 1 my_VERSION_MINOR)
list(GET my_VERSION_LIST 2 my_VERSION_PATCH)
message("1: ${my_VERSION_MAJOR}")
```

For the sake of Minimal reproducible example here is simple `demo.cmake`:

```
% cat demo.cmake
set(GIT_VERSION 1.2.3)
message("${GIT_VERSION}")
```

Now observe what I see on my ubuntu system:

```
% cmake .. && echo "first ok" && make rebuild_cache
1: 1.2.3

1: 1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/demo/bin
first ok
Running CMake to regenerate build system...
1: 1.2.3

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (list):
  list index: 1 out of range (-1, 0)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (list):
  list index: 2 out of range (-1, 0)


1: 1;2;3

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/demo/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** [Makefile:81: rebuild_cache] Error 1
```

So the cmake code seems to be valid on the first run but becomes invalid on second rebuild_cache...

Does anyone see the typo ?

Reference:

```bash
% cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.1
```

---

Update, the bizarre part is that this run fine:

```bash
% /usr/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S/tmp/demo -B/tmp/demo/bin
1: 1.2.3

2: 1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/demo/bin
```

---

Update2: Even more bizarre:

```bash
% make rebuild_cache >& my.log && cat my.log
Running CMake to regenerate build system...
1: 1.2.3

2: 1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/demo/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be an escape sequence parsing issue:

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25789#note_1497207

Verbatim copy:

> There are escape sequences in the output from demo.cmake when the
> message() goes to an interactive terminal (env CLICOLOR=0 make
> rebuild_cache avoids the problem).  The escape sequences have
> unbalanced square brackets in them, which we document as causing lists
> to not be split on ;.

So the solution is to replace `message` with a simple `echo`:

```
$ cat demo.cmake
set(GIT_VERSION 1.2.3)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ${GIT_VERSION})
```

Documentation being reference is:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#introduction

> Note: [...] Individual elements may not contain an unequal number of [
> and ] characters, and may not end in a backslash (). See
> semicolon-separated lists for details.