# Add space separated string to cmake `include_directories`

Tags: cmake

I have a space separated string that represents include directories I'd like to add, let's call it `${MYSTRING}`, and let's say it contains the string`my/dir1 my/dir2 my/dir3`.

Using:

```
include_directories(${MYSTRING})
```

Results in an incorrect makefile, as the `CXX_FLAGS` that is added is:

```
-Imy/dir1 my/dir2 my/dir3
```

Rather than:

```
-Imy/dir1 -Imy/dir2 -Imy/dir3
```

Is there anyway I can work around this? the string is generated via an external command, and I'd rather not have to depend on external tools such as `sed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is common way to split string into list with CMAKE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272781/what-is-common-way-to-split-string-into-list-with-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`separate_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/separate_arguments.html) which takes a space-separated string of values and turns it into a list:

```
set(MY_LIST ${MYSTRING})
separate_arguments(MY_LIST)
include_directories(${MY_LIST})
```