# Is there a function in CMake to reverse a string?

Tags: cmake

Is there a function in `Сmake` to reverse a string? I have a variable containing the string "abcd" and I need to get the string "dcba" from it. If there is no such function, what should I do?

I read the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html) but didn't find the required function there.

Comment: 1) you could use `execute_process` to run a command/program that reverses strings. But that might not score too well in the cross-platform category. 2) note: a related generator expression proposal is here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20614

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command. I would try splitting your string into a list, which requires adding a `;` character to split on, because:

> A list in cmake is a ; separated group of strings

Then reversing the list, then joining it back together. Something like:

```
string(REPLACE "" ";" output ${delimited})
list(REVERSE delimited reversed_list)
list(JOIN reversed_list "" reversed_string)
message(STATUS "reversed: ${reversed_string}")
```

This is entirely untested. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272993/743464) for more string/list manipulation examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function, but creating one is not so hard. Here is the one possible implementation:

```
#the function to reverse the string
function (string_reverse INPUT_STRING OUTPUT_VAR)

    string(LENGTH ${INPUT_STRING} len)
    set(out "")
    foreach(indx RANGE ${len})
        string(SUBSTRING ${INPUT_STRING} ${indx} 1 char)
        string(PREPEND out ${char})
    endforeach()

    set(${OUTPUT_VAR} ${out} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

The usage of the function `reverse_string` would be as follows. Please note that the code expects the function definition to be available now.

```
# prepare the string to be reversed
set(ORIGINAL_STRING "123 45 67 890 a b c d e fgh I J K LMNO  PQ")

# call the function to reverse the string
string_reverse(${ORIGINAL_STRING} REVERSED_STRING)

# debugging output
message ("ORIGINAL_STRING: ${ORIGINAL_STRING}")
message ("REVERSED_STRING: ${REVERSED_STRING}")
```

Note that the variable `REVERSED_STRING` will be created and initialized within the function, so it is unnecessary to do it explicitly.

After running this code, the output would be as follows:

```
ORIGINAL_STRING: 123 45 67 890 a b c d e fgh I J K LMNO  PQ
REVERSED_STRING: QP  ONML K J I hgf e d c b a 098 76 54 321
```

BTW, what are you trying to achieve? i.e., why do you need string reversal within cmake?