# CMake generated c++ project with system and standard includes

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, include, cmake

Regarding the title I found a lot of discussions but unfortunately no proper/universal answer.
For Eclipse CDT one could set the includes globally, but if your compiler changes you have to do it again.
Thus, I wrote the following working minimal example of a `CMakeFile.txt` to set the includes, which are used by the compiler.

```
# Check wheter required CMake Version is installed
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7 FATAL_ERROR)

# Set the project name to the name of the folder
string (REGEX MATCH "[^/]+$" PROJECT_NAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
message (STATUS "Set PROJECT_NAME to ${PROJECT_NAME}")
project ("${PROJECT_NAME}")

# Grep the standard include paths of the c++ compiler
execute_process(COMMAND echo COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only ERROR_VARIABLE GXX_OUTPUT)
set(ENV{GXX_OUTPUT} ${GXX_OUTPUT})
execute_process(COMMAND echo ${GXX_OUTPUT} COMMAND grep "^\ " OUTPUT_VARIABLE GXX_INCLUDES)

# Add directories to the end of this directory's include paths
include_directories(
    ${GXX_INCLUDES}
)

# Defines executable name and the required sourcefiles
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" main.cpp)
```

The `grep`ing of the includes is some pain in the a**, but it works.
Another point is, that it does not work for cmake above `cmake 2.8.7` concerning this bug  http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15211 .
So, I want to know if anyone have a better way to set the system includes?

Comment: the big question is: why do you need that at all??? normally, you shouldn't do that! compiler will know (and use) all system paths w/o any actions from your side.

Comment: You are absolutely right! One don't need it for compilation, but I want to create a proper project, like one for Eclipse CDT or whatever. Here you need all the paths, so that the IDE can resolve all the includes, functions and namespaces. It is just for convenience.

Comment: Then, why don't you use an appropriate generator? I suppose `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja"` should do the job!

Comment: @zaufi But this does not work with an arbitrary g++ compiler. Consider switching to an g++ cross-compiler environment. Then it definitely fails.

Comment: Classic XY problem. You don't want to know how to set up includes, you want to know how to set up a cross compilation project with CMake. Please check the documentation http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling Your approach is **not** what you want to do.

Comment: @pmr Thanks for the hint, I'll dig into it later, but for now my answer works great on all my systems. Another point is, that it only depends on the compiler which I've sourced into my environment. This way I can simply switch between compiling for my x86 or the ARM by running `cmake .` in the proper terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve it for even higher versions of cmake than cmake 2.8.7.
The point is, I have to work with lists seperated by `;`.
As zaufi mentioned, there is of course the build in possibility to add the standard includes, but this do only work with you standard environment, not with e.g. cross compiler environments.

So here is the working `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Check wheter required CMake Version is installed
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7 FATAL_ERROR)

# Set the project name to the name of the folder
string (REGEX MATCH "[^/]+$" PROJECT_NAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
message (STATUS "Set PROJECT_NAME to ${PROJECT_NAME}")
project ("${PROJECT_NAME}")

# Grep the standard include paths of the c++ compiler
execute_process(COMMAND echo COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only ERROR_VARIABLE GXX_OUTPUT)
set(ENV{GXX_OUTPUT} ${GXX_OUTPUT})
execute_process(COMMAND echo ${GXX_OUTPUT} COMMAND grep "^\ " COMMAND sed "s#\ ##g" COMMAND tr "\n" "\\;" OUTPUT_VARIABLE GXX_INCLUDES)

# Add directories to the end of this directory's include paths
include_directories(
    ${GXX_INCLUDES}
)

# Defines executable name and the required sourcefiles
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" main.cpp)
```